# How do I access TomEE's JTA transaction manager?

Tags: spring, jta, openejb, apache-tomee

I have an application that uses Spring's declarative transaction management. How can I deploy this in a TomEE+ container so that the application uses TomEE's JTA transaction manager?

More specifically, how can I refer to the built-in transaction manager from within Spring's "application-context.xml" file?

Spring's transaction management configuration seems to want to look up the transaction manager either by a bean reference or by JNDI lookup;  I have spent a day researching this and looking at source code; I have found a lot of discussion of the issue (references below) but no definitive how-to.

What I have in the application's META-INF/persistence.xml is this:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>myDs-managed</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>myDs-unmanaged</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" 
            value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.PostgresDictionary"/>       
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
        <property name="openjpa.Run
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="slf4j" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And, in the applications META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml file I have this: (I have tried various values for transactionManagerName as suggested in various discussions of the topic, as it appears to be non-standard across application servers

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="txManager" />
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
        id="txManager">
        <property name="transactionManagerName" 
                       value=" java:comp/TransactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

Here's an example that is claimed to work for JBoss: [Spring JTA configuration - how to set TransactionManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783540/spring-jta-configuration-how-to-set-transactionmanager)

Here's a near miss that won't work in an xml configuration file: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-38

Here's how to do it within java code if you have your hands on initialContext: http://osdir.com/ml/users.openejb.apache.org/2012-11/msg00110.html

[Edit: The Tomee documentation talks about how to declare a transaction manager, but it says to do it in Tomee.xml, which belongs to the server and not to the individual webapp; I want to configure the transaction manager for a single app and not for the whole server: http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html]

Comment: What is the class name of the transaction manager that JTA provides by default?  I notice that the TomEE+ distribution includes geronimo-transaction and openejb-core, both of which have a fair bit of transaction plumbing in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `java:comp/env/TransactionManager` for the transactionManagerName?
,
Also have you declared the TransactionManager and DataSource as described here: http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html?

Comment: Jukka, thank you, yes, I tried java:comp/env/TransactionManager.

I had looked at the documentation page you referenced, but it talks about declaring datasources and the transaction manager in tomee.xml, which as I understand it configures the entire server instance for all applications;  I just want to configure the datasoure and transaction manager for a single application. (edited question to clarify this)

Comment: Spring won't create the underlying container-managed transaction manager or datasources for you, so you need to declare them in tomee.xml (or some other container-specific config file). I do not know if TomEE allows you to limit their scope to a single app though.

Comment: But if you REALLY need to, you might be able to declare the TomEE transaction manager and datasources as beans in your spring config. But personally I would just have the container manage them and not worry about the details.

Comment: Jukka, "Just have the container manage them and not worry about the details" is exactly what I am trying to accomplish.  Could you help me do it?

Comment: It turned out to be easier than expected: 
`<bean id="transactionManager"  
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
  <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:comp/env/comp/TransactionManager"/>
  </bean>`